# Why does iPhone's Reminder App not show on home screen?

Tags: iphone

I just migrate from Nokia 5230 to iPhone5s. When I'm using iPhone Reminder App, I find that the reminder items are only accessible within the app. That is to say, you have to open the Reminder App to find things you may forget to do.

Let me repeat it again: You have to **Remember** to do something, that you may **easily forget**. But **if I can remember** to check for my reminder, then why I need this?

On the contrary, in my 5230, reminders could be easily viewd on desktop, so I don't have to remember to check my reminders.Everytime I glance at my 5230, I can quickly discover the to-dos.

Below is the avaibility comparison.

[image: iPhone]
[image: Nokia 5230]

So my question is: **Is this Reminder App a good design**? If it is, then **why design it in this way**? I just don't understand.

Or, I just don't know how to use the Reminder App?

Addtionally, items in Remember App could be timed to remind users. But **most to-dos just not works in that way**. For example, I don't know when to buy my tickets today. I just need to do it when I have a small interval during my work.

Comment: If you set a due date for a reminder it will show up in the Notification Center after the calendar in the Today overview. Apple probably wants you to look there for all information you want to glance upon, as it is also accessible from the lock screen. The only thing you should want to do on the home screen is to launch an app.

Answer (score 1):

Concettually, Apple's Notification Center is the same of the Nokia's home screen (desktop), where you have everything in front of you: calendar and reminders (if they have a date to remind). 
For example you could set a reminding date for tomorrow and today you could see the reminder for all the day, if you know how to use the notification center.

[image]

You have to think at the notification center like the old Nokia's home screen, while the actually iOS' home screen is like the old Nokia's menu screen, imho.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I don't use the default Reminder app, I use another app - Doit.im.

But it have the same principle - you should open the app to see the items. There are some pre-created folders: Today, Tomorrow, etc. And I check them during my day. There can be a lot of tasks and it would be total mess to see them somewhere in Notification Center.

But if the event is happening on some specific day in the future - I setup the reminder, usually two - 1) 1 day before the event, 2) 1-2 hours before the event. And the app reminds me about my ongoing tasks in Notification Center.

I'm used to it and find it useful.